# How does Caffe updates gradients of a blob with more than one output branch？

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

Caffe supports multiple losses. Then for the backpropagation stage, some blobs may have multiple gradients coming from different losses. How does Caffe do with the gradients of this blob?

As far as I know, this may not be a concern when designing networks. But this question really confuse me when I try to write a new layer. Thanks for any idea!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue of caffe or any other deep-learning tool. This is purely a mathematical question: When you have several losses, you have `loss_weight` assigned to each loss and the overall loss of the net is the weighted sum of all losses. Consequently, the gradients computed for the net are gradients of the weighted sum of the losses: there is no gradient-per-loss that needs to be integrated, but rather a single loss which is a weighted sum of loss layers.

Caffe usually uses [`"Split"`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/split.html) layer when directing the `"top"` of a layer into several layers (in your example the output of `"conv2"` is `"Split"` to a `"bottom"` of `"auxiliary loss"` and `"ip1"`).
Looking at the code of backward propagation of [`"Split"` layer](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/split_layer.cpp#L33-L49) you can see that the all `top.diff`s are summed into `bottom.diff`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know there is a `loss_weight` that controls the weight of each loss. But I still don't know how exactly Caffe implements it. I think in Caffe, each layer accepts `diff`of its top blobs, do computations, and pass results to `diff` of its bottom blobs via `mutable_cpu_diff()`. Take the above figure for example. The `conv2`'s top blob (name it `conv2` as convention)  is the bottom blob of `auxiliary` and `pool2` .  Both `auxiliary` and `pool2` will change their bottom blob's `diff` during backprop. Then how does `conv2` blob's `diff` be updated?

Comment: @C.Li it will update it as the gradient chain rule dictates

Comment: I get the idea of gradient chain rule. But I'm still not clear where and when Caffe implements it. Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @C.Li look at the Split layer caffe inserts after the conv layer. You should see it in the log when caffe loads the net

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how the gradients flow in the backprop stage. P.S Sorry for the late reply. It's a little inconvenient for me to access Stack Overflow.